# import encog examples into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, encog

I am trying to import encog example into eclipse. encog is basically a java library to implement neural network and another machine learning algorithm but I am keep getting the error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'encog-examples' is missing required Java project: 'encog-java-core'    encog-examples      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

any suggestion is highly appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this just right click on the project then build path configure build path project then I delete encog-java-core and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project --> Java Build Path --> Delete encog-java-core
2. Download encog-core-3.3.0.jar (or the version you need). Then add it to the Java Build Path